# MongoDB updating an object

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Currently working on a NodeJS backend with mongoDB. I'm trying to update an Object in mongoDB using NodeJS driver:

```
 "mongodb": "^3.0.2",
```

I am using the `findOneAndUpdate` query and have tried the following syntax:

**First syntax:**

```
updatedPlayerData = await db.db(MDBC.db).collection(MDBC.pC).findOneAndUpdate({
    'username': req.body.username
}, {
        $set: {
            [profession.city]: '',
            [profession.organisation]: '',
            [profession.profession]: ''
        }
    }, { returnOriginal: false });
```

**Second syntax:**

```
updatedPlayerData = await db.db(MDBC.db).collection(MDBC.pC).findOneAndUpdate({
    'username': req.body.username
}, {
        $set: { 
            profession: {
                city: '',
                organisation: '',
                profession: ''
            }
        }
    }, { returnOriginal: false });
```

Also have tried a bunch of other stuff. Can't seem to update the object properly. How can I properly update an object?

Comment: This should help `db.db(MDBC.db).collection(MDBC.pC).findOneAndUpdate(query, req.newData, {upsert:true}, function(err, doc){
    if (err) return res.send(500, { error: err });
    return res.send("succesfully saved");
});`

Comment: Don't use await, as mongo returns a callback function. otherwise you can wrap the 
 query code inside promise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this :

```
db.db(MDBC.db).collection(MDBC.pC).findOneAndUpdate({
    'username': req.body.username
}, {
        $set: {
            'profession.city': '',
            'profession.organisation': '',
            'profession.profession': ''
        }
    }, { returnOriginal: false });
```